# Why is my javascript recursion code not calculating the number of lines words and characters in a text file

Tags: javascript, recursion

Need help on why my recursion program in javascript is not working. It is supposed to take the words from the text file and display the number of words, lines and characters in it. Please help me modify my code or tell me where my mistake is because I do not know where. Here is the javascript code:

```
var fs = require("fs");
var text = fs.readFileSync("text.txt", "utf8");
function countLines(text) {
  if (text == "") {
    return 0;
  } else {
    return 1 + countLines(text.substring(text.indexOf("\n") + 1));
  }
}
function countWords(text) {
  if (text == "") {
    return 0;
  } else {
    return 1 + countWords(text.substring(text.indexOf(" ") + 1));
  }
}
function countCharacters(text) {
  if (text == "") {
    return 0;
  } else {
    return 1 + countCharacters(text.substring(1));
  }
}
var lineCount = countLines(text);
var wordCount = countWords(text);
var characterCount = countCharacters(text);
console.log(
  "There are " +
    lineCount +
    " lines, " +
    wordCount +
    " words, and " +
    characterCount +
    " characters in the file."
);
```

This is the text.txt file:

```
I was running to the zoo.
```

Comment: what is the result of running your code? Hint: indexOf returns `-1` when the target is not found

Comment: it says maximum call stack size exceeded at countlines undefined. Can you try to see if it works for you?

Comment: And its exited with code 1

Comment: hint: indexOf returns -1 when the target is not found - think what that means in your code - `text.substring(text.indexOf(" ") + 1)` ... `text.substring(-1 + 1)` ... `text.substring(0)`

Comment: so how do I get it to work then?

Comment: check to see if `indexOf` returns `-1` before blindly recursing the same string over and over - to be honest, I can't see why you use recursion for this anyway

Comment: For a homework assignment and it doesn't

Comment: so, it has to be recursive or not? I can't decode your previous comment - `characters = text.length` `words = text.split(' ').length` for example

Comment: Yea it has to be recursive, I had to do it two ways. One I already did which is map filter and reduce but now I have to do it with recursion.

Comment: oh, in that case, you'll need to check if `indexOf` returns `-1` and if so return `1`

Comment: so ... `if (text === "") return 0; if (text.indexOf(" ") < 0) return 1;` note, your code never needs `else` but that's a coding style choice

Comment: Do you think you could modify my code for me? Ill upvote it and it would just be more clear to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is blindly recursing without checking the result of indexOf, which is -1 when the target isn't found

so

```
text.substring(text.indexOf(" ") + 1)
```

becomes

```
text.substring(-1 + 1)
```

in other words

```
text.substring(0)
```

So, you infinitely recurse the last word (and line, for that matter)

If `.indexOf` returns -1, you should `return 1`

Note: I removed the unnecessary `else` in your code - no need for `else` when the `if` returns a value - this make for cleaner code (in my opinion, you're welcome to use else if you must

I've shown two different ways to test `indexOf`

```js
var text = "I was running to the zoo.";

function countLines(text) {
  if (text == "") {
    return 0;
  }
  const index = text.indexOf("\n");
  if (index  < 0) {
    return 1;
  }
  return 1 + countLines(text.substring(index + 1));
}

function countWords(text) {
  if (text == "") {
    return 0;
  }
  const index = text.indexOf(" ") + 1;
  if (index) { // since we've added 1, a "not found" -1 would be 0 here, and be falsey
    return 1 + countWords(text.substring(index));
  }
  return 1;
}

function countCharacters(text) {
  if (text == "") {
    return 0;
  } 
  return 1 + countCharacters(text.substring(1));
}
var lineCount = countLines(text);
var wordCount = countWords(text);
var characterCount = countCharacters(text);
console.log(
  "There are " +
  lineCount +
  " lines, " +
  wordCount +
  " words, and " +
  characterCount +
  " characters in the file."
);
```

Answer (score 1):

If we are counting lines, the base case is not `if (text == "")`, it is when no `\n` is found in `text`. Changing the base case can result in a new way to think about the problem and a simplification of our code.

Given *i* is the position of `\n` in the string *text* -

1. If *i* is less than zero, *text* is the last line. Return `1`.
2. (inductive) *i* is 0 or greater, *text* has more than one line. Return `1` plus the result of the sub-problem.

```js
function countLines(text) {
  const i = text.indexOf("\n")
  if (i < 0) return 1                                // 1
  else return 1 + countLines(text.substring(i + 1))  // 2
}

console.log(countLines(`Hello`))

console.log(countLines(`Hello
World,`))

console.log(countLines(`Hello
World,
We don't deserve you.`))
```

We could be less verbose with a ternary expression -

```js
function countLines(text) {
  const i = text.indexOf("\n")
  return (i < 0) ? 1 : 1 + countLines(text.substring(i + 1))
}
```